# Add bunch of images to a user Mongodb Nodejs React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, backend

> Hello,
> I'm in a situation where I create users and have one admin who can see every users.
> What I want to do is that the admin can add images to the users database (and user could see his files)
> so everything work but I absolutely don't know how to add files to users as a user (here the admin)
> I know there is other ways to put an admin role but this one fit for me now.

> The user have as file as the admin add.

> here is the code what I made about that
>
> [user model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0N5n.png)
> [user creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6fak.png)
> [what admin see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWCcn.png)
> [function onSubmit form (to add a file) not done yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5PDb.png)
> [mongodb collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY4j7.png)

> I think I'm gonna add a patch to upload the factures field but for now I don't know where and how add fil anyway.
> The file would be add in the category "factures" now is only a String but I think we could do that differently.
> I tried with a simple mutter but it doesn't worked.
> thank you for reading this and may be help me about that.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, post them as plain text with code format. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask